# Display mysql result column wise html

Tags: html, mysql

I would like to show mysql out put result row wise to column wise. Here is my html

```
PHP Formated
    <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="prc">
       <?php 
         $i = 1;
         while($res = mysql_fetch_array($query)){  ?>
         <span class="pb<?php echo $i; ?>"> $res['name']</span>
         <?php $i++; } ?>
      </div>
    </li>
    </ul>

Orginal HTML
 <ul>
        <li>
          <div class="prc">
          <span class="pb1">sample data</span>
          <span class="pb2">sample data</span>
          <span class="pb3">sample data</span>
          <span class="pb4">sample data</span>
          </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

### CSS

```
.pb1 , .pb2, .pb3 , .pb4
{
display: block;
float: left;
border-right: 2px solid #F9F9F9;
width: 24%;
text-align: center;
min-height: 90px;
}
```

### Output Obtained

MARK 
   JOSEPH  
   PRINCE  
 
   JOHN  
   MICK

### Output Expected

```
MARK |  JOSEPH |  PRINCE | JOHN | MICK
```

How to get this kind of ouptut.

Comment: It looks like that's what you're doing. You don't have any line breaks between the rows, so they should all be on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="prc">    
<ul>


           <?php 

             $i = 1;
             while($res = mysql_fetch_array($query)){  ?>
    <li>
             <span class="pb<?php echo $i; ?>"> $res['name']</span>
    </li>
             <?php $i++; } ?>


        </ul>
   </div>
```

put li inside your loop and thats it

Comment: Won't that put each list item on a separate line? Do you need CSS to get them back on the same line?

Answer (score 0):

Assign the class to li instead of the span and you will get your desire output

```css
.pb
{
display: block;
float: left;
border-right: 2px solid #F9F9F9;
width: 24%;
text-align: center;
min-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="prc"> <ul>
          
          <li class="pb"><span >sample data</span> </li>
          <li class="pb"><span >sample data</span> </li>
          <li class="pb"><span >sample data</span> </li>
          <li class="pb"><span >sample data</span> </li>
          

</ul>
  </div>
```

Don't know why are you assign same css with different class name. Here is the way as you want to achieve:

**You PHP code:**

```
<div class="prc">
<ul>
   <?php 
     $i = 1;
     while($res = mysql_fetch_array($query)){  ?>
     <li class="pb">
     <span> $res['name']</span>
     </li>
     <?php $i++; } ?>
</ul>
</div>
```